# VSTS Gradle SonarQube - Unhandled: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, azure-devops

I'm using VSTS (custom Windows Agent) to run a java (8) Gradle build, tests and SonarQube analysis. I'm using the SonarQube extension from the marketplace (SonarQube plugin 4.x).
SonarQube version: Version 5.6.7

When running the build "gradlew clean build" without SonarQube it works perfectly. However, when enabling the same build with SonarQube for Gradle, I get the following error at the end of the build.

```
:build
:sonarqube
Classes not found during the analysis : [org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerException, org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager, org.springframework.security.openid.AxFetchListFactory, org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter, org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationToken, org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDConsumer]
Cobertura report not found at E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent3\48\s\target\site\cobertura\coverage.xml
The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
  apply
  test
  commence
  get
  applyAsInt
  accept
  toPredicate
  convert
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 34.795 secs
47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da exists true
47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da exists true
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Only single test suite found, parsing its information
Unhandled: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Unhandled: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
```

EDIT: system.debug = true

```
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3426878Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'gradlew build'
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3426878Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3426878Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3426878Z ##[debug]=> (Boolean) True
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3426878Z ##[debug]Expanded: True
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3426878Z ##[debug]Result: True
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3426878Z ##[section]Starting: gradlew build
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3476897Z ==============================================================================
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3476897Z Task         : Gradle
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3476897Z Description  : Build using a Gradle wrapper script
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3476897Z Version      : 1.128.0
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3476897Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3476897Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613720)
2018-02-26T10:14:05.3476897Z ==============================================================================
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6176927Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6226929Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6226929Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6278448Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da_PASSWORD
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6278448Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da_USERNAME
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6278448Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6326898Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6326898Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6326898Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6326898Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CHECKSTYLEANALYSISENABLED
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6326898Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CLASSFILESDIRECTORIES
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6326898Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CODECOVERAGETOOL
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6376914Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CWD
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6376914Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_FAILIFCOVERAGEEMPTY
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6376914Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_FINDBUGSANALYSISENABLED
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6376914Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_GRADLEOPTS
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6376914Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_JAVAHOMESELECTION
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6426902Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_JDKARCHITECTURE
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6426902Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_JDKVERSION
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6426902Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PMDANALYSISENABLED
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6426902Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PUBLISHJUNITRESULTS
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6426902Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQANALYSISBREAKBUILDIFQUALITYGATEFAILED
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6426902Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQANALYSISENABLED
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6476886Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQANALYSISINCLUDEFULLREPORT
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6476886Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQCONNECTEDSERVICENAME
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6476886Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQDBDETAILSREQUIRED
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6476886Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQGRADLEPLUGINVERSION
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6476886Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQPROJECTKEY
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6526901Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQPROJECTNAME
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6526901Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SQPROJECTVERSION
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6526901Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TASKS
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6526901Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TESTRESULTSFILES
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6526901Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_WRAPPERSCRIPT
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6576923Z ##[debug]loading SECRET_SONARQUBE_ENDPOINT
2018-02-26T10:14:05.6576923Z ##[debug]loaded 32
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5760473Z ##[debug]check path : E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\1.128.0\task.json
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5760473Z ##[debug]set resource file to: E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\1.128.0\task.json
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5760473Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5810271Z ##[debug]wrapperScript=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5810271Z ##[debug]check path : E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5810271Z ##[debug]Append .bat extension name to gradlew script.
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5810271Z ##[debug]cwd=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5810271Z ##[debug]check path : E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5860364Z ##[debug]javaHomeSelection=JDKVersion
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5860364Z ##[debug]codeCoverageTool=None
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5860364Z ##[debug]failIfCoverageEmpty=false
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5860364Z ##[debug]publishJUnitResults=true
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5860364Z ##[debug]testResultsFiles=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\**\TEST-*.xml
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5860364Z ##[debug]tasks=build
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5860364Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5860364Z ##[debug]options=null
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5910238Z ##[debug]E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat arg: ["build"]
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5910238Z ##[debug]Using JDK version to find and set JAVA_HOME
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5910238Z ##[debug]jdkVersion=default
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5910238Z ##[debug]jdkArchitecture=x64
2018-02-26T10:14:06.5910238Z ##[debug]Agent.Version=2.123.0
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=Tasks.CrossPlatform;feature=Gradle]{"jdkVersion":"default"}
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]gradleOpts=-Xmx1024m
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]GRADLE_OPTS is now set to -Xmx1024m
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]Enabled code coverage successfully
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqAnalysisEnabled=true
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z SonarQube analysis is enabled.
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqAnalysisEnabled=true
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqGradlePluginVersion=2.6.2
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat arg: ["sonarqube"]
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat arg: ["-I","E:\\VSTSBuilds\\Agent2\\_tasks\\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\\1.128.0\\node_modules\\codeanalysis-common\\sonar.gradle"]
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqConnectedServiceName=47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da=https://sonarqube.bpweb.bp.com/
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug][SQ] SonarQube endpoint: https://sonarqube.bpweb.bp.com/
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z 47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da exists true
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da exists true
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z 47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da exists true
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da exists true
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat arg: -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.bpweb.bp.com/
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat arg: -Dsonar.login=********
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat arg: -Dsonar.password=********
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqDbUrl=null
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqDbUsername=null
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqDbPassword=null
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqProjectName=hopper-api
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqProjectKey=com.bp.WellHopper:hopper-api
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqProjectVersion=sonarqube-scan_20180226.2
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat arg: -Dsonar.projectName=hopper-api
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat arg: -Dsonar.projectKey=com.bp.WellHopper:hopper-api
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat arg: -Dsonar.projectVersion=sonarqube-scan_20180226.2
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]Running a full SonarQube analysis
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]sqAnalysisEnabled=true
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]build.artifactStagingDirectory=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\a
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]build.buildNumber=sonarqube-scan_20180226.2
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]checkstyleAnalysisEnabled=false
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]findbugsAnalysisEnabled=false
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]pmdAnalysisEnabled=false
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]Getting credentials for account feeds
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]Got auth token
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1681605Z ##[debug]exec tool: E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]Arguments:
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]   build
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]   sonarqube
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]   -I
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]   E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\1.128.0\node_modules\codeanalysis-common\sonar.gradle
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]   -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.bpweb.bp.com/
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]   -Dsonar.login=********
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]   -Dsonar.password=********
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]   -Dsonar.projectName=hopper-api
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]   -Dsonar.projectKey=com.bp.WellHopper:hopper-api
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z ##[debug]   -Dsonar.projectVersion=sonarqube-scan_20180226.2
2018-02-26T10:14:07.1731850Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\gradlew.bat build sonarqube -I E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\1.128.0\node_modules\codeanalysis-common\sonar.gradle "-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.bpweb.bp.com/" "-Dsonar.login=********" "-Dsonar.password=********" "-Dsonar.projectName=hopper-api" "-Dsonar.projectKey=com.bp.WellHopper:hopper-api" "-Dsonar.projectVersion=sonarqube-scan_20180226.2""
2018-02-26T10:14:08.1966657Z :bootBuildInfo UP-TO-DATE
2018-02-26T10:14:09.4579355Z :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
2018-02-26T10:14:09.5379345Z :generateGitProperties
2018-02-26T10:14:09.5479335Z :processResources UP-TO-DATE
2018-02-26T10:14:09.5479335Z :classes
2018-02-26T10:14:09.6579594Z :findMainClass
2018-02-26T10:14:10.0962930Z :jar
2018-02-26T10:14:10.6312944Z :bootRepackage
2018-02-26T10:14:10.6312944Z :assemble
2018-02-26T10:14:10.6362966Z :instrument SKIPPED
2018-02-26T10:14:10.6362966Z :copyCoberturaDatafile SKIPPED
2018-02-26T10:14:10.9212980Z :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
2018-02-26T10:14:10.9212980Z :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
2018-02-26T10:14:10.9262995Z :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
2018-02-26T10:14:10.9712994Z :test UP-TO-DATE
2018-02-26T10:14:10.9712994Z :generateCoberturaReport SKIPPED
2018-02-26T10:14:10.9764453Z :performCoverageCheck SKIPPED
2018-02-26T10:14:10.9764453Z :check UP-TO-DATE
2018-02-26T10:14:10.9764453Z :build
2018-02-26T10:14:31.4780792Z :sonarqube
2018-02-26T10:14:31.4780792Z Classes not found during the analysis : [org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerException, org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager, org.springframework.security.openid.AxFetchListFactory, org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter, org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationToken, org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDConsumer]
2018-02-26T10:14:33.2281680Z Cobertura report not found at E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\target\site\cobertura\coverage.xml
2018-02-26T10:14:41.7976552Z The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
2018-02-26T10:14:41.7976552Z   apply
2018-02-26T10:14:41.7976552Z   test
2018-02-26T10:14:41.7976552Z   commence
2018-02-26T10:14:41.7976552Z   get
2018-02-26T10:14:41.7976552Z   applyAsInt
2018-02-26T10:14:41.7976552Z   accept
2018-02-26T10:14:41.7986587Z   toPredicate
2018-02-26T10:14:41.7986587Z   convert
2018-02-26T10:14:44.5770689Z 
2018-02-26T10:14:44.5770689Z BUILD SUCCESSFUL
2018-02-26T10:14:44.5770689Z 
2018-02-26T10:14:44.5770689Z Total time: 37.817 secs
2018-02-26T10:14:45.0076796Z ##[debug]rc:0
2018-02-26T10:14:45.0076796Z ##[debug]success:true
2018-02-26T10:14:45.0126798Z ##[debug]sqAnalysisEnabled=true
2018-02-26T10:14:45.0126798Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1076800Z ##[debug][SQ] Searching for E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\**\build\sonar\report-task.txt - found 1 file(s)
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1126794Z ##[debug]sqConnectedServiceName=47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1126794Z ##[debug]47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da=https://sonarqube.bpweb.bp.com/
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1126794Z ##[debug][SQ] SonarQube endpoint: https://sonarqube.bpweb.bp.com/
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1126794Z 47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da exists true
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1126794Z ##[debug]47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da exists true
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1126794Z 47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da exists true
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1126794Z ##[debug]47053fcc-a958-4b7f-9f92-cb5f104699da exists true
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1126794Z ##[debug]sqAnalysisIncludeFullReport=true
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1126794Z ##[debug][SQ] Getting the quality gate status 
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1126794Z ##[debug][SQ] Waiting for SonarQube analysis to complete.
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1176799Z ##[debug][SQ] Invoking API at: /api/ce/task?id=AWHRm4Anw5-0Oa-uTcuT
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1226797Z ##[debug][SQ] Waiting for SonarQube analysis to complete.
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1226797Z ##[debug][SQ] Invoking API at: /api/ce/task?id=AWHRm4Anw5-0Oa-uTcuT
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1226797Z ##[debug]Gradle result: 0
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1226797Z ##[debug]Processing code analysis results
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1226797Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1226797Z ##[debug]build.artifactStagingDirectory=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\a
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1226797Z ##[debug]build.buildNumber=sonarqube-scan_20180226.2
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1226797Z ##[debug][CA] Attempting to find report files from 3 code analysis tool(s)
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1276812Z ##[debug]checkstyleAnalysisEnabled=false
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1276812Z ##[debug][CA] Checkstyle analysis is not enabled.
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1276812Z ##[debug]findbugsAnalysisEnabled=false
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1276812Z ##[debug][CA] FindBugs analysis is not enabled.
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1276812Z ##[debug]pmdAnalysisEnabled=false
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1276812Z ##[debug][CA] PMD analysis is not enabled.
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1326782Z ##[debug][CA] Skipping artifact upload: No analysis results
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1326782Z ##[debug]Pattern found in testResultsFiles parameter
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1326782Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s
2018-02-26T10:14:45.1326782Z ##[debug]find findPath=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s, options=undefined
2018-02-26T10:14:45.2126789Z ##[debug]651 results
2018-02-26T10:14:45.2126789Z ##[debug]match patterns: E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\**\TEST-*.xml
2018-02-26T10:14:45.2126789Z ##[debug]match options: [object Object]
2018-02-26T10:14:45.2126789Z ##[debug]applying pattern: E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\**\TEST-*.xml
2018-02-26T10:14:45.2276792Z ##[debug]matched 15 items
2018-02-26T10:14:45.8156931Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.ExpectedPressureDepletionCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9306932Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9406931Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.GrossReservoirAverageThicknessCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9406931Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.OverallChanceOfSuccessCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.RecoveryFactorCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.ReservoirDeliverabilityRiskIndexCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.ReservoirTypeCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.RiskedResourceCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.StaticGiipCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.TargetDefinitionIndexCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.TargetQualityCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9456880Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.TotalRemainingResourceCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9506892Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9506892Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.TotalResourceCalculationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9556913Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9556913Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.TargetValidationTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9556913Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9556913Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.validation.BigDecimalMaxSignificantDigitsValidatorTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9556913Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9556913Z ##[debug]Reading test results from file 'E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.service.HopperAuditListenerTest.xml'
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9556913Z Only single test suite found, parsing its information
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9856930Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[results.publish type=JUnit;mergeResults=true;publishRunAttachments=true;resultFiles=E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.ExpectedPressureDepletionCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.GrossReservoirAverageThicknessCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.OverallChanceOfSuccessCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.RecoveryFactorCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.ReservoirDeliverabilityRiskIndexCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.ReservoirTypeCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.RiskedResourceCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.StaticGiipCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.TargetDefinitionIndexCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.TargetQualityCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.TotalRemainingResourceCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.calculations.TotalResourceCalculationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.TargetValidationTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.domain.validation.BigDecimalMaxSignificantDigitsValidatorTest.xml,E:\VSTSBuilds\Agent2\79\s\build\test-results\test\TEST-com.bp.hopper.service.HopperAuditListenerTest.xml;]
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9856930Z ##[debug]task result: Succeeded
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9906933Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]Build succeeded.
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9906933Z ##[debug]Request failed because of error: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9906933Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[error]Unhandled: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Unhandled: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Unhandled: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[debug]self signed certificate in certificate chain
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[debug]Could not fetch task details on ID AWHRm4Anw5-0Oa-uTcuT
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[debug]Request failed because of error: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[error]Unhandled: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Unhandled: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Unhandled: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[debug]self signed certificate in certificate chain
2018-02-26T10:14:45.9956935Z ##[debug]Could not fetch task details on ID AWHRm4Anw5-0Oa-uTcuT
2018-02-26T10:14:46.0006933Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Telemetry
2018-02-26T10:14:46.0006933Z ##[section]Async Command End: Telemetry
2018-02-26T10:14:46.0006933Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2018-02-26T10:14:46.2306934Z Publishing test results to test run '9130'
2018-02-26T10:14:46.2306934Z Test results remaining: 103. Test run id: 9130
2018-02-26T10:14:47.2003990Z Published Test Run : https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/yyyyyyyy/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=9130&_a=runCharts
2018-02-26T10:14:47.2003990Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2018-02-26T10:14:47.2003990Z ##[section]Finishing: gradlew build
```

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: Yes, got a bit more info with system.debug set to true (see above)

Comment: Can you share the whole build log?

Comment: Sorry, can't share the file on OneDrive (restricted access by company)

Comment: Edited the output with the logs (less the files in the workspace)

Comment: After further investigation, I noticed that it fails only when the checkbox "Include full analysis report in the build summary (SQ 5.3+)" is ticked. When unticked, the job is successful.

Comment: I see that you are using version 1.128.0 of the Gradle Task. Maybe you should upgrade to the latest 2.x version?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam where do you set the project.name/key/version in version 2.0 of the plugin? These settings seem to have disappeared.

Comment: Everything's explained in https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html

Comment: Perfect! I simply had to add the sonar.projectKey to the build.gradle

Comment: What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes it works now. I used the Gradle plugin 2.x and the new Sonar config. Though I had to add sonar.projectKey in the build.gradle following the SonarQube doc. Thanks for your help